# How to create follow leader behavior?

Tags: libgdx, ai, steering-behaviors

Assume that this behavior has `Separation` behavior. I tried to implement the `FollowLeader` behavior from this [article](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understanding-steering-behaviors-leader-following--gamedev-10810). In the code below is my working implementation. But there is a problem, when I convert the owner linear velocity to direction (North, South, East, West), it doesn't give the proper direction to achieve the correct facing of my animation.

```
    protected SteeringAcceleration<T> follow(SteeringAcceleration<T> steering, Steerable<T> leader) {
        T tv = leader.getLinearVelocity().cpy();
        // calculate the ahead point
        tv.nor();
        tv.scl(LEADER_BEHIND_DIST);
        ahead = leader.getPosition().cpy().add(tv);

        // calculate the behind point
        tv.scl(-1);
        behind = leader.getPosition().cpy().add(tv);

        if(isOnLeaderSight(leader, ahead)) {
            evade.calculateSteering(steering);
            force.add(steering.linear);
        }

        arrive(steering, behind);
        force.add(steering.linear);

        // separation(..) assume exists

        steering.linear.set(force);
        steering.angular = angular;

       return steering;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, it's a little bit different when implementing using Gdx-ai. Here is the solution.

```
BlendedSteering<Vector2> followLeader = ...

followLeader.add(new ArriveBehind(owner, leader), 1f);
followLeader.add(new Evade(owner, leader). 1.5f); // tweak until matches, for me I used 1.5f

setBehavior(followLeader);
```

Then in the update method. Enable the evade behavior only if in the leader sight or ahead.

```
evade.setEnabled(isOnLeaderSight(leader, getAhead(leader)));
```